# Matching available languages to language names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, named-scope

I want to make a language selection dropdown in a site user edit/create page.

For this purpose, I have of course translated the site to more than one language.
Using I18n.available_languages, I can then get an array of locale codes, like so

```
development environment (Rails 2.3.4)
> I18n.available_locales
   => [:en, :da]
```

Furthermore, I have created a Language model and related it to User:

```
# app/models/language.rb
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users  
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language  
end

# db/schema.rb
create_table "languages", :force => true do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "code"
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "language_id"
end
```

The language table then contains a locale code and a language name in the native tongue, like so:

```
| id  | name                | code |
------------------------------------
| 28  | Dansk               | da   |
| 29  | Nederlands          | nl   |
| 30  | English             | en   |
| 31  | Esperanto           | eo   |
```

I then have the following assignment in the User new, create and edit actions:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb (extract)
@available_languages = I18n.available_locales.collect {|language_code| Language.find_by_code(language_code.to_s)}
```

which I use in the view like so ('available_languages' is a local variable, since @available_languages from the controller has been passed to a partial):

```
# app/views/users/_form.haml (extract)
= f.collection_select(:language_id, available_languages, :id, :name, {:prompt => true})
```

The upshot of all this, is that the user will get a locale select dropdown to define the locale for the given user.

My question is:
Is there a clean way to move the @available_languages assignment out of the UsersController and into the Language model, so I can shorten this:

```
@available_languages = I18n.available_locales.collect {|language_code| Language.find_by_code(language_code.to_s)}
```

to something like this:

```
@available_languages = Language.translations_available
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you're doing a couple of funny things. First off there are some problems with the following:

```
I18n.available_locales.collect {|language_code| Language.find_by_code(language_code.to_s)}
```

This setup causes you to generate one SQL query for every available locale. Furthermore if every locale in `I18n.available_locales` has a corresponding `Language` object and vice-versa, this code seems a bit unnecessary. You might as well just do:

```
Language.find(:all) # or even Language.all
```

If for some reason, they don't map directly, you could use this instead:

```
Language.all(:conditions => { :code => I18n.available_locales })
```

which in a more verbose form is equivalent to:

```
Language.find(:all, :conditions => ["code IN (?)", I18n.available_locales])
```

This will find all languages whose code is listed in I18n.available_locales. If you want a shortcut to this method, you can use named_scopes:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

  named_scope :translation_available, :conditions => { :code => I18n.available_locales }
end
```

With this, you can then call:

```
Language.translation_available
```

I think this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Peter. The Language table does not map directly, so I'll try out Language.all(:conditions => { :code => I18n.available_locales })

Comment: If you need an authoritative list of all two-letter language codes that map to I18n translation .yml files, my guess is this list is pretty authoritative: http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php --- for a list of language names in their native tongues, you might use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Answer (score 13):

I add a "locale_name" key to each yml with it's language name in it's own language as well.
For example:

in es-AR.yml

```
es-AR:
  locale_name: "Castellano"
```

in en.yml

```
en:
  locale_name: "English"
```

Comment: I18n.t('locale_name') or in erb simply t('locale_name')

Comment: What if you want a combobox with all locales?

Comment: I'd do something like: options_for_select AVAILABLE_LOCALES.map{|l| [I18n.t(l), l]}

Answer (score 13):

Here's a more complete answer based on Dwaynemac's solution:

1. Add a key with the locale name to each yml file. For example in en.yml:

   ```
   en:
     language: English
   ```

   and in es.yml:

   ```
   es:
     language: Español
   ```
2. Add a helper method (for example in /app/helpers/application_helper.rb) which creates an array of locale and locale name pairs:

   ```
     def locale_name_pairs
       I18n.available_locales.map do |locale|
         [I18n.t('language', locale: locale), locale.to_s]
       end
     end
   ```
3. In your form use `locale_name_pairs` to create your selection dropdown:

   ```
   f.select :locale, options_for_select(locale_name_pairs, @user.locale)
   ```

**Note for the lazy:** If you prefer to skip step 2 then you can use the following one-liner in step 3:
`f.select :locale, options_for_select(I18n.available_locales.map{ |locale| [I18n.t('language', locale: locale), locale.to_s] } , @user.locale)`